# Collecting many printf calls in a single string

Tags: c++

I am dealing with some code that performs RC4 encryption algorithm with some params passed into the function. From there I am trying to append the generated hash to an empty string but have failed with a few of my attempts. I had seen the use of `snprintf()` but how could I go about converting the code below to save what gets printed to a string?

```
    for (size_t i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++) {
        printf("|x%02hhx| ", hash[i]);
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you have with `snprintf()`?  The only difference is that you specify a buffer and a size.

Comment: I guess im having trouble appending the string i am trying to save to. I have my empty string declared outside the loop
`std::string stored_text = ""` and within my loop I tried to append the string like `stored_text += snprintf(buffer, size, "%02hhx", hashtext[index]);
`

Comment: @aaries Try instead to construct a string from the buffer and concatenate, something like `stored_text += std::string(buffer)` after the call to `snprintf`.

Comment: @aaries What does `snprintf` [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?  Given that, does it make sense to append an integer onto your string?  The data is in buffer, so shouldn't you be appending that buffer?

Answer (score 7):

Why not use C++.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char plaintext[] = "12345";
    char hash[] = "123\xf0\x0f";
    std::stringstream out;
    for (size_t i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++) {
        out << "|x"
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::setbase(16)
            // ok, maybe this is the reason.
            << 0xff & hash[i]
            << "| ";
    }
    std::cout << out.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just work with `std::string::data` after determining the size of the output of `std::snprintf`:

```
template<class...Args>
std::string PrintFToString(char const* format, Args...args)
{
    std::string result;
    char c;
    int requiredSize = std::snprintf(&c, 1, format, args...);
    if (requiredSize < 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("error with snprintf");
    }

    result.resize(requiredSize);

    int writtenSize = std::snprintf(result.data(), requiredSize+1, format, args...);
    assert(writtenSize == requiredSize);

    return result;
}

template<class...Args>
void AppendPrintFToString(std::string& target, char const* format, Args...args)
{
    char c;
    int requiredSize = std::snprintf(&c, 1, format, args...);
    if (requiredSize < 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("error with snprintf");
    }

    auto const oldSize = target.size();
    target.resize(oldSize + requiredSize);

    int writtenSize = std::snprintf(target.data() + oldSize, requiredSize+1, format, args...);
    assert(writtenSize == requiredSize);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << PrintFToString("|x%02hhx| ", 33) << '\n';

    std::string output;
    for (int i = 0; i != 64; ++i)
    {
        AppendPrintFToString(output, "|x%02hhx| ", i);
        output.push_back('\n');
    }

    std::cout << output;
}
```

Note: If you know a reasonable upper bound for the number of characters of the output, you could use a char array allocated on the stack for output instead of having to use 2 calls to `std::snprintf`...